# Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbf{R}$ and $L,L' \in \mathbf{R}$. If $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L'$, show that $L'=0$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, functions, proof-writing, solution-verification

> Let $f:(0,\infty)\to \mathbf{R}$ be differentiable on $(0,\infty)$ and $L,L' \in \mathbf{R}$. Suppose that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=L$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L'$. Prove that $L'=0$. I know that there are a few posts on this statement, but I didn't see my approach. So, I would like to know if my proof holds, please. In the following proof I will distinguish 2 cases: (1) $L'>0$ and (2) $L'<0$

(1) Suppose that $L'>0$. As  $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=L'$ exists, then there $\exists M>0 \ \forall x\ge M:0<\frac{B}{2} \le f'(x)$. Thus, $f$ is strictly increasing on $[\frac{B}{2},\infty)$.

Let $[x,x+a]\subset [\frac{B}{2},\infty)$ with $a>0$. As $f$ is differentiable on $(0,\infty)$, it is differentiable on $[x,x+a]$ as well and so continuous. By MVT we have then that there $\exists c_x \in ]x,x+a[$ such that:

$f'(c_x)=\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}$ and by inserting a limit on RHS and LHS we have $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(c_x)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}=0$. As $f$ is increasing and $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)$ exists, we can conlude that $\lim_{x\to\infty}f'(x)=0$.

**(2)** The proof is similar to the previous one, but this time we have that $\exists M>0 \ \forall x\ge M$: $f'(x)<-2B<0$ and we have that $f$ is decreasing on $[M, \infty)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your proof is technically correct (modulo the typo $[B/2, \infty)$ should be $[M, \infty)$ everywhere). I think there is a simpler approach. Note that $f'(x) \geq B/2$ doesn't just imply that $f$ is increasing, it actually implies (just integrate both sides) that $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x) = \infty$, a contradiction. If this is for homework and you have not learned about integration yet, then I would stick with your original approach though.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, oh yes it might be $[M,\infty)$. No, it isn't homework and I saw integration already. I see the idea! Thank you for another approach

Answer (score 1):

I think you do not even need to divide two cases. Since you already know that a limit of $f'(x)$ with $x\rightarrow +\infty$ exists you can write that $L'=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty}f'(x) =\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty} f'(c_x)=\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow +\infty} \frac{f(x+a)-f(x)}{a}=\frac{1}{a}(L-L)=0$. The second equality is true because $c_x\in (x,x+a)$ converges to $+\infty$ if $x$ converges to $+\infty$ and because of the fact that any subsequence of converging sequence converges to the same limit. The last step you can explain in different ways, I named just one of way.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good, but you can see that in (1) since $\exists M>0$ such that $\forall x\geq M$ $: f'(x)>B/2>0$ if you integrate the last inequality you have that $f(x)-f(M)>B/2(x-M)$ $ \forall x\geq M$ and taking $x\to\infty$ you obtain that $L=\infty$ and contradiction. For (2) is the same reasoning.